# MongoDB: Getting the list of all databases?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How do I list all databases for a connection using Mongo C# Driver?

Comment: alternatively, from the shell: `> show dbs`

Comment: you can use *show collection* command on cmd..!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Very easily:

```
var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost/?safe=true");
var databaseNames = server.GetDatabaseNames();
```

Answer (score 8):

The MongoServer class was deprecated in version 2.0.0.

You can use ListDatabasesAsync

```
using (var cursor = await client.ListDatabasesAsync())
{
    await cursor.ForEachAsync(d => Console.WriteLine(d.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Working Solution:**

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
using (IAsyncCursor<BsonDocument> cursor = client.ListDatabases())
{
    while (cursor.MoveNext())
    {
        foreach (var doc in cursor.Current)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(doc["name"]); // database name
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The MongoServer class was deprecated in version 2.0.0 as Juri pointed out. If you don't want to use async, here's how I do it:

```c#
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://" + server_username + ":" + server_password + "@" + server_host + ":" +  server_port);

List<MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument> databases = client.ListDatabases();
```

Just one thing. It is in BsonDocument format that has 2 elements: "name" and "sizeOnDisk".

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able validate if a given DB exists or not with the existing answers, so here's my take on it:

```
    // extension method on IMongoClient
    public static IMongoClient AssertDbExists(this IMongoClient client, string dbName)
    {
        bool dbFound = false;

        using(var cursor = client.ListDatabases())
        {
            var databaseDocuments = cursor.ToList();
            foreach (var db in databaseDocuments)
            {
                if (db["name"].ToString().Equals(dbName))
                {
                    dbFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!dbFound) throw new ArgumentException("Can't connect to a specific database with the information provided", nameof(MongoSettings.ConnectionString));

        return client;
    }
```

And then use it like this:

```
// either you get the client with the DB validated or throws
_client = new MongoClient(settings.ConnectionString).AssertDbExists(_dbName);
```

**Using:** Mongo Official C# driver v2.4.4