# Connection to a query router (mongos) from C# and list databases

Tags: c#, mongodb

I nee to connect to a mongo and run a commands.
I'm am connecting using the following piece of code.  I want to test weather I am connecting by listing the databases.

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017");
client.ListDatabases();
```

If I debug and click on the second line I cannot see the names of the databases. How can I print the names of the databases to screen to confirm I am connected to mongo.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/csharp/client/  I would put a breakpoint on client.ListDatabases(); then hover using intellisense to inspect what client consists of. Can even do a quickwatch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: Getting the list of all databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105678/mongodb-getting-the-list-of-all-databases)

Comment: Yes that is what i did but I cannot see any database names I have created

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify credentials in the Connection String.  Couple ways you can do this:

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://user1:password1@127.0.0.1:27017";
```

Is the format expected, you will have to supply the username and password yourself, these are just placeholders.

Or you can create a `MongoCredentials` object and use that instead of a connection string (probably a bit cleaner this way, and allows more configuration if you look deeper into the object documentation)

```
var credential = MongoCredential.CreateMongoCRCredential("test", "user1", "password1");

var settings = new MongoClientSettings
{
    Credentials = new[] { credential }
};

var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
```

Both of these examples are found on [MongoDB's documentation site](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tutorial/authenticate-with-csharp-driver/)

Comment: I did not create any credentials so I need no to pass any credentials in the connection string

Answer (score 0):

Try `GetDatabaseNames()` method and also assign the result to a variable. So that you can inspect it at breakpoint like

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/");
var databaseNames = client.GetDatabaseNames();
```

Comment: Yep sorry, removed my comment, but the latest NuGet package for MongoDb doesn't have a reference to GetDatabaseNames() either, but couldn't quickly find a doc showing it was deprecated.

Comment: @MattDearing, nope it's not deprecated at all and is still there but newer version of driver may not have it. See here http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/1.1/html/dd019888-5d24-5686-0cb8-3d046cee6acc.htm

Comment: okay as of 1.1 it was there, as of at least 2.2 it is not:
http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/2.2/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_MongoClient.htm

Answer (score 0):

`ListDatabases` returns an `IAsyncCursor` so try the following:

```
var client = new MongoClient(<CONNECTION STRING>);
var cursor = client.ListDatabases();
cursor.ForEachAsync(db => Console.WriteLine(((BsonString)db["name"]).Value));
```